# Why does $A \in$ SO(2) and $A \ne I \implies $ker$(A-I) = \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I've come across this in proofs for Euclidean geometry a few times. Can someone tell me why this is true?
$$A \in \text{SO}(2) \text{ and }  A \ne I \implies \text{ker}(A-I) = \{0\}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A\in\textrm{SO}(2,\mathbb{R})\setminus\{I_2\}$, there exists $\theta\in\mathbb{R}\setminus 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ such that: $$A=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}.$$
Therefore, one gets: $$\det(A-I_2)=(\cos(\theta)-1)^2+\sin^2(\theta)=2(1-\cos(\theta))\neq 0.$$
Finally, $A-I_2\in\textrm{GL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $\textrm{ker}(A-I_2)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Could you clarify why  $A-I_2 \in \text{GL}(2) \implies  \ker(A-I_2) = \{0\}$?

Comment: This is a general fact. Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $A\in\textrm{GL}(n,R)$. Let $X\in\textrm{ker}(A)$, by definition $AX=0_{R^n}$ and left-multiplying by $A^{-1}$ leads to $X=0_{R^n}$. Finally, $\textrm{ker}(A)=\{0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, compute the eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ as given in C. Falcon's post to be $e^{\pm i\theta}$. If $ker(A-I)\neq\{0\}$, then there is some eigenvector $\vec{x}$ of $A$ with corresponding eigenvalue $1$. So, $e^{\pm i\theta}=1$ implies $\theta=2\pi k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ implies $A=I$.